# PHPExcel - How to make different text backgorund in a cell

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to format a cell like different background color in a single cell. How do you create a different background color in a cell using PHPExcel? My requirement is suppose in cell A1 there is a text 'Hello World', I want 'Hello' text should be in red background and 'World' text should be in green. Hope this will make you clear what I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
$objRichText = new PHPExcel_RichText();

$objRed = $objRichText->createTextRun('red');
$objRed->getFont()->setColor("FFFF0000");

$objRichText->createText('Hello');

$objGreen = $objRichText->createTextRun('green');
$objGreen->getFont()->setColor("FF008000");

$objRichText->createText('World');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')->setValue($objRichText);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is not my requirement. My requirement is suppose in cell A1 there is a text 'Hello World', I want 'Hello' text should be in red background and 'World' text should be in green. Hope this will make you clear what I want.

Comment: I think you can not get my requirement, anyways thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: Hey brother this is not an issue of changing the color of text...as I said early you still not understand my requirement. Please read once more I am not trying to change the text color I and talking about text background color within a cell.

Comment: You are still not reach my requirement. Please read once again I am not yet want text color, my requirement is text background color. I think you have messed-up with text color and text background color. Both are not same hope this time you can clearly identify what I want.

Comment: Excel doesn't support this. you can't change half a cell to a different color than the other half of the cell.

Comment: I expect people to be aware of technical limitations. But i also learn much from this run around.